# call an Edit controller belonging to another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone tell me if it is possible to call an Edit controller belonging to another view from any view. I tried the following:

```
 <input type="button" value =" Ship?" style= "height: auto; width: auto" ONCLICK="window.location.href = '/Dispatch/Edit'">
```

As edit looks for an id or Primary Key which I normally do as an @ActionLink, an error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely do that.

Try:

```
@Html.ActionLink
```

Or:

```
@Url.Action
```

Both of the above have overloads that accept controller and action.

If you're after a POST the following also has a controller and action parameters overload:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok so how can I re-create the following:  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.ShippingId}), in another view?